# No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, modulenotfounderror

Pip does not work.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

None of the solutions of related issues solves it.
Should I reinstall [Anaconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) and a hundred of site-packages? Is it the only solution?

Answer (score 7):

Try this in [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

Comment: tried that, but I got `/usr/bin/python: No module named 'pip'`

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Comment: Actually, pip seems to work fine in other environments, only in the base one it does not work.

Comment: This helped me with a Flask app that somehow got stuck to get is back working. Needed to reinstall some pip packages though.

Answer (score 6):

Run the following command to solve the problem.

```
conda install -c conda-forge pip
```

Comment: this is the one that did it for me

Comment: worked for me. I was updating pip from spyder. the command first uninstalled the old version and while installing the upgrade, an error of access permission occurred, when i restarted spyder with administrative role, the old version was uninstalled already, and hence a disaster. but the above command worked for me.

Comment: My problem arises from running 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' (Anaconda Prompt). After this upgrading try, I cannot use pip anymore.  Thankfully, this solution solved my problem. My suggestion for those using Anaconda is that you should not upgrade your pip as I had did.

Answer (score 1):

Installation behavior on Windows 11 is different from
that on Windows 10.

Installing Python 3.9 using [Miniconda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)) is different from installing Python 3.8 on Windows 11. `pip install -U` did not work in Python 3.8 on Windows 11. Install Python 3.9 on Windows 11.

On [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) on Windows 11 and 10, all Python versions, such as Python 3.8 and 3.9, work fine.

Answer (score 1):

i have used pip freeze > req.txt and delete the current virtual environment, i have created new virtual environment and install all the libraries with command:
pip install -r req.txt and it is no more showing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip3` instead of `pip` i.e. `pip3 --version`

Comment: What platform (operating system, incl. edition and version), pip version, Python version, etc. was it tested on? 'pip3' hints at later versions of [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29), but it could be something else.